# Netezza SQL to find Client IP

Tags: netezza

Is there any way to return the client IP address in Netezza? In Oracle we run below query .

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual;

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query can get you all the information you need about the current_session.

```
select client_ip
from _v_session_detail
where session_id= CURRENT_SID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "show session" to provide that information if you aren't trying to access it as a column in a table.

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> show session;
 SESSION_ID |  PID  | USERNAME | DBNAME | SCHEMA | TYPE |    CONNECT_TIME     | SESSION_STATE_NAME |   SQLTEXT    | PRIORITY_NAME | CLIENT_PID | CLIENT_IP | CLIENT_OS_USERNAME
------------+-------+----------+--------+--------+------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------------
      16228 | 10272 | ADMIN    | SYSTEM | ADMIN  | sql  | 2014-12-10 10:56:48 | active             | show session | normal        | 10271      | 127.0.0.1 |
(1 row)
```

You can also query against the _v_session, which will report on sessions you have visibility/authorization to see, but doesn't necessarily tell you which one is yours. For a non-administrative user this is usually only your sessions, so it should be easy to tell.

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from _v_session;
  ID   |  PID  | USERNAME | DBNAME | TYPE |      CONNTIME       | STATUS |         COMMAND          | PRIORITY |  CID  |  IPADDR   | CLIENT_OS_USERNAME
-------+-------+----------+--------+------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+--------------------
 16228 | 10272 | ADMIN    | SYSTEM | sql  | 2014-12-10 10:56:48 | active | select * from _v_session |        3 | 10271 | 127.0.0.1 |
(1 row)
```

If you want information only about the particular session in which you are calling the query, then this will do the trick.

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from _v_session where id = current_sid;

  ID   |  PID  | USERNAME | DBNAME | TYPE |      CONNTIME       | STATUS |                     COMMAND                     | PRIORITY |  CID  |  IPADDR   | CLIENT_OS_USERNAME
-------+-------+----------+--------+------+---------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+--------------------
 16837 | 22310 | ADMIN    | SYSTEM | sql  | 2014-12-10 19:06:21 | active | select * from _v_session where id = current_sid |        3 | 22309 | 127.0.0.1 |
(1 row)
```

I should note that what you're looking for here is already being tracked by the query history database, which is most likely already configured on your system.

Comment: My actual requirement is to log the Client machine IP of the users who execute the procedures. Querying _V_session will return multiple rows if more than one users are connected .    Looking for a replacement for below function.                                                          

 create or replace function F_USER_IP return varchar2 is
  V_IP Varchar2(25) ;
begin
  SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') into V_IP FROM dual;
  return(V_IP );
end F_USER_IP ;
THANKS.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Updated to reflect that.  Note that what you're asking for is already tracked for you in the query history database (which is most likely already configured on your system), if you aren't trying to integrate this into some other application.